# Include .c files in Unit test project and get access to it from multiple cpp files without linking problems

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

I'm doing functional testing on c code. Have include .c file in test .cpp file so far, everything works well. But I need to include the same .c file in another .cpp file where I do other unit tests. Then I get problems that is already defined. Because I already include it in the first file cpp.

If merge all the test methods into one cpp file then it works well. If keep all unit test in one file get to big handle so I need to split up diffrent files in same project it also create help functions for secure that functions get in capsules.

This not a normal LNK2005 because I can not declare the variable and functions in .h: as extern BOOL MyBool; and then assign to it in a .c or .cpp file. Because need include c file as I do unit test this function. Also I can't or should avoid do any changes .c.

I looking way to keep include of .c local not effect other files in same project.

source.h

```
#ifndef SOURCE_H_
#define SOURCE_H_

#include "../car.h"

enum INITIALMODE {
   INITIALMODE_NOT_POSITIONING,             // 0
   INITIALMODE_NO_DRIVER_INPUT,             // 1
   INITIALMODE_POSITION_LOW_POSITION,       // 2
   INITIALMODE_POSITION_STANDARD_POSITION,  // 3
   INITIALMODE_POSITION_HIGH_POSITION       // 4
};
void initMotor(void);
#endif
```

source.c

```
/* Compiler include files */
#pragma once

#include "positioning.h"
#include "api.h"
#include "drive.h"
#include "types.h"

static void updateTarget(void);
static SWord getMax(UWord Limit, UWord Aux);
static DWord getHeight(void);
static Bool isMode(void);
static Bool isExiting(void);

#define cMaxHeight      100 * Profile.s.Max /* m -> mm */

void initMotor(void)
{
   // do something
}

static void updatePositioning(void)
{
   // do something
}
```

Test files look like this, however, this is very scaled for making exemple small.

**UnitTest.cpp** and **UnitTest2.cpp**

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#ifndef UNIT_TEST
#define UNIT_TEST

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Test
{

    extern "C" {
     #include "../../Test/source.h"
     #include "../../Test/source.c"
    }

TEST_CLASS(UnitTest_1)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD(Test_1)
    {
        // Verify that the initial state is as expected.
        initTest();

        //Expected value
        UWord Expected = 500
        //Trigger to execute.
        UWord Test = updatePositioning();

        // Verify that the results are as expected.
        Assert::AreEqual(Expected, Test);

      }
   };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was you in the other question as well, just that it seemed to ask the same thing. Reopening here.

Comment: You should never include `*.c` or `*.cpp` files, no matter what. If you use some variables/functions/classes in multiple translation units, you should declare them first in a header.

Comment: @YoungDevelopers, please edit your question to include some sample code that you wish to test and I will explain how to test it. I don't want to write an answer which will probably be unclear to you.

Comment: You ask how you can test functions un multiple .cpp files? Why not simply compile your .c file, and include the .h in your .cpp files? Note that if you're testing c code in c++, there are other issues to consider, but I agree with @Ptaq666 that you should never include a .c or .cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never include a .C or .CPP file.

However, you can compile C code in C++. Here's an example based on the information you gave in your initial post.

**YourCCode.h**

```
#ifndef YourCCode_H
#define YourCCode_H

int FunctionToTest(int SomeParams);

int TestStaticFunctions(int SomeParam1, int SomeParam2);

#endif // YourCCode_H
```

**YourCCode.c**

```
#include "YourCCode.h"

static int SomeStaticFunction(int Param1, int Param2)
{
  return Param1 + Param2; // that needs extensive testing, obviously.
}

int FunctionToTest(int SomeParams)
{
  return SomeStaticFunction(SomeParams, 1); 
}

int TestStaticFunctions(int SomeParam1, int SomeParam2)
{
  return SomeStaticFunction(SomeParam1, SomeParam2);
}
```

**UnitTest1.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
#include "YourCCode.h"
}

bool TestFunction(int Value)
{
  return (FunctionToTest(Value) == Value+1);
}
```

**UnitTest2.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
#include "YourCCode.h"
}

void AnotherTestFunction(int Val, int Val2)
{
  int newValue = TestStaticFunctions(Val, Val2);
  ASSERT(newValue == Val+Val2);
}
```

Then compile your CPP and C file.

---

After you clarified your intent, I realized you're trying to test static functions from another unit. Static function, by definition, are only available to other functions in the same translation unit. This is mostly use as a protection to prevent programmers to call some functions without knowing how to validate their inputs, know the call order, etc...

My best bet here is either you choose that your functions are not static and you can test them from outside your translation unit, or you implement the test functions inside the translation unit containing those static functions. I would recommend the latter as a translation unit should know (architecturally speaking) how to test their own features.

---

As a third solution, if you don't have any control over the content of the C file (but since you have that C file, I doubt it), you could have a proxy CPP file that includes the C file, and create a proxy call for each static call.

That is a ugly hack, though, and could break very easily if the C file ever gets updated, so I'm advising against it.

Here's a quick example :

**YourCCode.h**

```
#ifndef YourCCode_H
#define YourCCode_H

void SomeFunction(void);

#endif // YourCCode_H
```

**YourCCode.c**

```
#include "YourCCode.h"

static int AddSomething(int Param1, int Param2)
{
  return Param1 + Param2;
}

static int SubtractSomething(int Param1, int Param2)
{
  return Param1 - Param2;
}

void SomeFunction(void)
{
  // code meant to be called externally.
}
```

**ProxyTestCode.hpp**

```
bool TestAddSomething(void);
bool TestSubtractSomething(void);
```

**ProxyTestCode.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
#include "YourCCode.h"
#include "YourCCode.c"
}

bool TestAddSomething(void)
{
  return (AddSomething(2,2) == 4);
}

bool TestSubtractSomething(void)
{
  return (AddSomething(2,2) == 0);
}
```

**UnitTest1.cpp**

```
#include "ProxyTestCode.hpp"

void TestAdd(void)
{
  ASSERT(TestAddSomething());
}
```

**UnitTest2.cpp**

```
#include "ProxyTestCode.hpp"

void TestSubtract(void)
{
  ASSERT(TestSubtractSomething());
}
```

If you do that, **don't** compile your C file in your project.

Comment: Just compile the C files, exactly as you're doing your CPP files.

Comment: Okay, I haven't realized this yet, but are you trying to test static functions?

Comment: Yes, I change your code make behave almost like my code without static function and variables. Try fix that first without changes .h and .c files

Comment: You can't include a file containing at least one non-static function in multiple units and compile them together. That just won't work. I'm editing my post to explain that more in details.

Comment: @YoungDevelopers, now your question is more clear. The purpose of testing is to test the public functions only (in C language - non static) (you want to test the functionality, not the way it is implemented). All solutions allowing you to test private (static) function are just some ugly hacks.

Comment: The purpose of a static function or variable is literally to hide the function or variable away from a programmer. You hide it inside a translation unit so that others (units/programmers) can't mess with them and break the functionality of the unit. So, architecturally, testing internal and hidden functions is the responsability of the translation unit which hides these functions. Anything else is an ugly hack, and a ugly hack is by definition not easy to maintain.

Comment: So, I guess my third solution didn't help you?

Comment: It solves the problem even if it get some extra code.